# How to extract normals from mesh to png?

Tags: python, normals, normal-map

How do i get a normal map like this from a simple face mesh in Blender? I need it for further use in the algorithm of face reconstruction.
[image: My mesh]
[image: Desired png]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like normals baked in object space. Surprisingly I couldn't find a tutorial on the Internet that's not about baking from high poly to low poly, so here's mine:

Go to shading tab, add a new material if there isn't one already [image], <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>, search for Image texture, **don't connect it to anything**, create a new image by pressing a button on the Image Texture node you just created [image], **keep this node selected** (white border).

Now in the Properties panel, in Render settings [image] change Render engine to Cycles, then in *Bake* section change *Bake type* to *Normal*, then *Influence > Space* to  *Object*, and click the *Bake* button [image].

Once baking is finished [image], go to Texture Paint or UV Editor workspace and you should be able to see and save your image:

[image]

Looking at your image, it's front of a face that has a lot of blue on entire surface, so the face faces the positive Z direction. The right side gets red (+ blue = pink), so X increases to the right. The top of wrinkles get green, so Y goes up. Look at your project and even position the face accordingly, or change swizzling in *Bake > Influence* settings. By default, Suzanne looks at -Y, +Z is on the top, +X on the right, so only X is correct, the rest has to be changed:

[image]

I also added smooth shading, baked:

[image]

Finally, your example might be misleading, but perhaps you want to put it on your mesh as color and render the image - in such case just connect the node you've put in the material, to the *surface* socket of the *Output node*:

[image]

Comment: The bake would look better with subdiv mod, also I didn't mention setting image texture to non-color mode, because in my testing, the resulting saved image didn't care about this setting. The last setting does, however, though it cancels out if you set the view transform to Standard (which I didn't, left it at Filmic...).